# Samsung printer successfully connected to wireless network but not pingable by client

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-printer, printer

I'd like to connect a printer to my wireless network which also serves three desktop client PCs. The only way to use the printer at the moment is to connect it directly to one of the clients via USB. The printer successfully connects to the wireless network via WPS or manual settings. Although the printer status page says *everything's fine* the printer's IP address does is unreachable from the clients.

The printer is a **SAMSUNG SXC-4623FW**, all desktop clients run **Windows 7**, the router is a **Speedport W724V** DSL modem/router that establishes a **WPA2-Personal TKIP-AES encrypted** wireless network, uses **DHCP** and has the **IP 192.168.2.1**.

It makes no difference whether the printer connects automatically to the network by WPS or if I set IP, gateway and subnet mask manually. For reference, they are:

```
IP:          192.168.2.105
Gateway:     192.168.2.  1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
```

Unfortunately, the router does not show which clients are connected to its network so I have no way of telling whether the printer is really connected to the network. At least it says so on the status print out. The router serves **802.11a/b/g/n** and channel is set to *Auto*.

Any ideas why the printer is not reachable?

**UPDATE**: Upon tackling the problem a second time a few days later, I was surprised that the printer was suddenly reachable by all clients. The only explanation I can think of is, that it was necessary to restart all clients (because that's the only thing that happened since). Setting up the printer for WiFi access is child's play once it responds to a ping…

Comment: Is client isolation enabled on the router? If so, that would cause the symptoms you describe.

Comment: Please let us know what router model you have, some just isolate entierly the WLAN from the LAN.

Comment: Is it feasible to connect it to one PC by USB and enable printer sharing on that PC?

Comment: The router is a **Speedport W724V**. It offers only very few configuration options and I didn't find an option about AP isolation. It doesn't seem like isolation is in place, because the three clients can receive pings amongst each other. 

Enabling printer sharing would be a feasible workaround but I had hope that regular WLAN printing worked.

Comment: WHat are the IP addresses of the PCs? Are they on the same subnet (192.168.2.x)?

Comment: They are (and always have been) in the same subnet. I also tried DHCP and statically setting the IP. But as I wrote in the update above, it now miraculously works after having restarted all PCs.